# How to integrate REDHAWKSDR into Eclipse Che?

Tags: eclipse, redhawksdr, codenvy, web-ide, eclipse-che

I am currently trying to figure a way to integrate my REDHAWKSDR environment into my Eclipse Che environment. I have both of these software installed and configured individually, but I would like them to be in the same environment, preferably based in the Eclipse Che, so all I would have to do is open Eclipse Che and REDHAWKSDR would be included in the environment. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The tech stack for Eclipse Che is different than the tech stack for the Eclipse IDE (and hence the Redhawk IDE). Therefore it is not possible to install Redhawk IDE software into Eclipse Che.